# Mystery currency that doesn't work

Tags: r, list, quantmod

**Aim:** I am trying to find currency conversions for 67 currencies to USD.

Data: Here is the list of currencies:

```
currency <-c("ALL", "AMD", "AZN", "BIF", "BOB", "BRL", "BZD", "CLP", "CNY", 
"COP", "CRC", "DOP", "EGP", "EUR", "GEL", "GHS", "GTQ", "HNL", 
"HTG", "IDR", "ILS", "INR", "JOD", "KES", "KGS", "KHR", "LAK", 
"LBP", "LRD", "LSL", "MDL", "MGA", "MMK", "MNT", "MWK", "MXN", 
"MZN", "NAD", "NGN", "NIO", "NPR", "PEN", "PHP", "PKR", "PYG", 
"RWF", "SBD", "SLL", "SRD", "SSP", "THB", "TJS", "TRY", "TZS", 
"UAH", "UGX", "USD", "VND", "VUV", "WST", "XAF", "XCD", "XOF", 
"YER", "ZAR", "ZMW", "ZWD")
```

**What I've done:**

Using the `getQuote` function from the `quantmod`library, I have been able to get most of the quotes as follows:

```
#Split list of 67 currencies into groups of 10
from_chunks <- split(currency),
      ceiling(seq_along(currency)/10))

#Get length of each group
length_chunks <- lapply(from_chunks,length)

#Make a vector of length equalt to from_chunks with desired currency USD. 
to_chunks <- lapply(length_chunks,rep,x="USD")

#Function that takes many currencies and converts them to one
quote_batches <- function(from,to){
return(quantmod::getQuote(paste0(from, to, "=X")))
}

#Apply to the entire list
mapply(quote_batches,from_chunks,to_chunks)
```

**Problem:** The problem I'm having and the reason why split the 67 currencies into groups of 10, is that the not all the chunks are running. Chunks 5 and 7 give this error:

```
Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : invalid 'row.names' length
```

For the rest of the chunks, it works fine:
[image]

Why? Please advise :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `SSP` and `ZWD` produce 404 errors. Just try:

```
quantmod::getQuote("SSP=X")
quantmod::getQuote("ZWD=X")
```

You can easily find this by using a loop

```
for (ccy in currency)
  tryCatch(quantmod::getQuote(paste0(ccy, "=X")), error = print)
```

Comment: OMG, thank you so much. This was driving me nuts. Thanks for the intro to `tryCatch` too.